# Objective C Convenience Method Use

Tags: objective-c, class, methods

I am tring to understand convenience methods.

IF I have a sqlite database containing store details and am returning these store details in a FMResultSet. I am thinking that to create an array of these store details as Store objects, that the best way would be create an object of type Store in one go in a convenience method and add to array.

The Class I have created is as below with convenience method

```
@interface StoreDetails : NSObject   

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *storeName;
etc etc etc

+ (instancetype)storeWithStoreName:(NSString *)storeName 
                   TelephoneNumber:(NSString *) 
                   telephoneNumber: etc .......
```

My ResultSet loop would be as below?

```
NSMutableArray *Stores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while ([rs next]) {
    Store *store = 
    [Store storeDetailsWithStoreName:[rs stringForColumn:@"storename"] 
                            telephoneNumber:[rs stringForColumn:@"TelephoneNo"]];

    [Stores addObject:store];
}
```

Is my thinking correct as above is is it better to go as below.

```
NSMutableArray *Stores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

while ([rs next]) {
    Store *store = [Store alloc] init];
    store.storeName = [rs stringForColumn:@"storename"];
    store.telephoneNumber = [rs stringForColumn:@"TelephoneNo"];
    [Stores addObject:store];
}
```

All I am trying trying to understand is why you would use one over the other in noob speak, thankyou.

Comment: It's probably a ridiculous idea, but why don't you try your code and see if it does what you want?!

Comment: I am trying to understand convenience methods use and know my code works so have already tried it. I wanted to know If I am doing things correctly.

Comment: Personally, my convenience method for something like this, would be passed the record set, handle the looping and creation of `Store` objects and return the `NSMutableArray`

Comment: I have re-worded the question to maybe make it more clear what I am asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a good approach: initializing your Store object in a method of the Store class.

The `storeDetailsWithStoreName:...` method you have defined is a good example of what Apple calls a *[factory method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html)* (assuming you aren't doing anything weird in its implementation). It's a quite common pattern; Foundation has all sorts of examples: `arrayWithCapacity:`, `numberWithInt:`, etc.

With ARC, the simplest examples of these factory methods are nearly identical to a corresponding alloc/init expression, since the developer no longer has to think about autoreleasing objects. But there are still plenty of uses for factory methods, e.g. special instantiation patterns such as singleton or flyweight, including a small amount of common conversion or formatting code for convenience, implementing [class clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html), etc. And there's the simple convenience of not having an extra set of brackets and less indentation.

The `instancetype` keyword is a good choice. This allows you to send the same message to a subclass of `Store`, with the expectation that the method will instantiate an object of the subclass using the same init method, like this:

```
+ (instancetype)storeWithStoreName:(NSString *)storeName 
                   telephoneNumber:(NSString *) 
                   ...
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithStoreName:...];
}
```

In the code above, as it's a class method, the `self` in `[self alloc]` is the Class object (either Store or a subclass of Store) rather than a specific instance of Store. This is what allows creating an instance of the correct class at runtime, depending on whether you call `[Store storeWithStoreName:...]` or `[MoreSpecificStoreSubType storeWithStoreName:...]`.

The alternative to a factory method, or compliment to it really, is to declare a custom `init` method in your Store class:

```
- (id)initWithStoreName:(NSString *)storeName
        telephoneNumber:(NSString *)telephoneNumber ...
```

…and use that directly inside your loop, instead of a factory method. Again, with ARC, not much of a difference between the two unless there's extra work you want to do in the factory method. You can have multiple variants of the `init` method; the standard practice is for all of them to call the most detailed init method, which is called the [*designated initializer*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html).

I would recommend taking the time to read the Apple documentation pages on standards for class design (I linked to some of these pages above). Since there are a lot of this is based more on convention rather than language design restrictions, it's important to know all about the patterns and best practices for good design and proper behavior of special methods.